# Label y-axis ticks with musical note name

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a chart data table with series values as **numbers** (these are MIDI note numbers - e.g. 60 is middle C, 61 is Db).

But for the user, the chart y-axis ticks should be the note **names**.

How can I do that please?

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. Can you show us what you have tried to do so far and any errors you have come across? You might want to check: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks, I should have done that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using object notation, you can provide the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`) for each tick

```
{v: 60, f: 'C4 (middle C)'}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [1, 60],
    [2, 61]
  ], true);

  var options = {
    vAxis: {
      ticks: [
        {v: 60, f: 'C4 (middle C)'},
        {v: 61, f: 'C#4/Db4'},
      ]
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Where can I find the full documentation on G charts?