# Google charts how to display friendly time duration labels?

Tags: google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to build a graph highlighting response times percentiles

- On the X axis I have the percentiles from 1 to 100
- On the Y axis, I have the the response time in seconds (I used a log scale).

To make the graph readable, I'd like to show friendly labels for values of the Y axis (or the datapoint themselves). It also makes sense to use the log of the duration so I can easily show days, weeks or months on the same graph. I found out it's possible to add labels to a series.

The problem, is that I have too many values, so if I show the friendly label on each datapoint, it's too hard to see anything

Here is how it looks like

[image]

When I see this, I say to myself, that it would make sense to only show the data label for one out of X datapoints (in this graph, maybe one out of 4 would look rather neat). Is there some way to easily do this ? Or maybe there's some other approach that could be used to have a nice graph representaiton of durations ?

Also, is there a way to "translate" the values of the Y axis instead of adding the labels on the datapoints ? (the number of seconds does not make sense but the number of days or months does, I'm using a Ruby helper to generate those values, but if something similar exists in Google I'd gladly take it)

EDIT : [the source sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zWqVjfmtSd6qgMTwVvXR90ZNwKmxoC1A-yBQ115sjpk/edit?usp=sharing) if you'd like to experiment

Comment: I'm not that familiar with charts in sheets, but using JavaScript, we can customize the y-axis labels using the `ticks` option. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60949499/5090771) is an example...

Answer (score 1):

The solution could be to create an additional column specifically for annotations and specify it as a label for the series. I did the following:

1. Add a new column `Annotation`
2. Fill it with a formula `=if(MOD(ROW(),5)=0,B2,"")` so that every fifth row has a value
3. `Chart editor` -> `Setup` -> `Series` -> `Label` point to the `Annotation` column
4. `Chart editor` -> `Customize` -> `Series` -> `Data labels` -> `Type` point to the `Custom`

Result:

[image]